# How do you simplify a problem like the one below?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the following: $\frac{25e^{25}}{15e^{6}}$

I got to $\frac{5}{3}e^{19}$ but I can't simplify it any more, or can I?

Comment: Nope you can't. But you can make it look nicer using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get it much simpler than that. One might consider $\frac{5e^{19}}{3}$ a bit neater, but that's purely a matter of aesthetics.